# unable to find bundled java version ..(Windows)

Tags: java, flutter, sdk

I have this error when I run the command flutter doctor:

```
unable to find bundled java version
```

My OS is: Windows 11

I have tried many solutions but they did not work. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I managed to solve it by creating a symbolic link with the following command in PowerShell in the folder `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio:`

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path .\jre -Target .\jbr
```

Hope it works for you too, good luck!