# Unable to find bundled Java version, I get errors in my development so i cant move forward

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, version

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDmlw.png)]

Here is a picture from the `flutter doctor -v`. i am not sure if its the error of new version android studio. Past releases link are broken as well. Hence, I am stuck here.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX21X.png)]

Here are my versions of flutter, android studio and java. One thing to be noted, my new version of android studio was giving issues in the environment variables so after trying jdk 8,11 only 16 allowed me to use the studio.

OS: Windows 11(latest version)

P.S. I only have one android studio folder in the android folder. I can not just delete it, right?

Comment: See if the solution in the link solves it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75122314/13158691

Comment: no, it did not, thats the error is got:

`New-Item : The directory is not empty.
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Program File...roid Studio\jre:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemDeleteIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
`

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem and found the solution.

So the **solution** to this problem is:

1. Go to your AndroidStudio folder

> (e.g. C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio)

2. There you'll find the `jbr` and `jre` folder So what you need to do is to copy the content of jbr and paste the content into the **jre** folder.

Comment: which jdk did you use? 17 or 19?

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved mine:
I installed the old version of [Android studio(v2021.3.1.17)](https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/2021.3.1.17/android-studio-2021.3.1.17-windows.exe) and JDK 16. Everything working fine now.